# The if command is not performed as desire. Maybe due to non local variables?

Tags: perl

I need to split two different types of records in a Perl program.
Every record comes with a distinct code (ZBKPF_W and ZBUS2081_W) so they have different processing depending on that.

The information comes from parsing the file name and at the end I should get the right command based on the right parsed fields.
However, the if command in Perl apparently does not obey it and in half of the cases, I get the wrong data.

Please allow me to show the process:
2 different types of documents to process that need to be split:

```
   # get info from filename and process each file
   # BO-CC-FY-DOCID-KOFAX#.PDF
   # ZBKPF_W-DE10-2020-1900000001-00034113.PDF and
   # ZBUS2081_W-DE10-2019-5106000000-00034114.PDF 
   ( $fileindex, $filetype) = split( '\.', $dir[i] ); 
   $fname = $dir[i]; 
   $BO = "";
   $CCode = "";
   $FY = "";
   $DocNo = "";
   $KofaxNo = "";
   $CCDocNoFY = "";
   $CCFYDocNo = "";   
   
   # Get the index values from filename 
   ( $BO, $CCode, $FY, $DocNo, $KofaxNo ) = split( '\-', $fileindex );
          
   if ( $BO == "ZBKPF_W" ) {
     $R3_SAP_OBJ = "ZBKPF_W";
     $CCDocNoFY = $CCode.$DocNo.$FY;
     $CCFYDocNo = $CCode.$FY.$DocNo; 
   }
   else {
     if ( $BO == "ZBUS2081_W" ) {
       $R3_SAP_OBJ = "ZBUS2081_W";
       $CCDocNoFY = $DocNo.$FY;
       $CCFYDocNo = $FY.$DocNo;
     }
   }
```

So, at the end, all the records look like ZBUS2081_W
Results:

```
$R3_SAP_OBJ = "ZBBUS2081_W"
$CCDocNoFY = $DocNo.$FY
$CCFYDocNo = $FY.$DocNo
```

always provides the else of the if command.

The correct results should be:

```
For ZBKPF_W-DE10-2020-1900000001-00034113.PDF
$R3_SAP_OBJ = "ZBKPF_W"
$CCDocNoFY = "DE1019000000012020"
$CCFYDocNo = "DE1020201900000001"
For ZBUS2081_W-DE10-2019-5106000000-00034114.PDF
$R3_SAP_OBJ = "ZBUS2081_W"
$CCDocNoFY = "51060000002019"
$CCFYDocNo = "20195106000000"
```

I have tried to use nested IF, ELSEIF and also using local variables with MY
Same results... I don't usually prefer Perl, so I far from an expert but this is a requirement for ArchiveLink, so I need it to run smoothly.

Please, if you have an idea why could be the root cause of the issue, I will appreciate that.

Comment: *Always* use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have foun your problem.

Comment: Tip: `if (...) { ... } else { if (...) { ... } }` can be written as `if (...) { ... } elsif (...) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` compares numbers in Perl. Use `eq` to compare strings.

When using a string starting with `Z`, it's coerced to number 0, so the first condition is always true.

See [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop) for more details.

Comment: It worked perfect after changing to eq. Thank you very much Choroba for your help. May you explain what it means that if the string starts wit Z it is coerced to number 0, please? Also thank you very much for the perlop, very valuable guide. Thank you again

Comment: @JoseGala It is not just "z", it is any string that does not begin with a number. Perl tries to cast the string to a number, and it will give a warning, if `use warnings` is enabled. My guess is that you do not have warnings enabled, and that is a very bad idea, as you can see.

Comment: Thank you again. No USE WARNING used, you are right. But I prefer to use your recommendation (eq) for strings and (==) for numbers, from now. Thank you for take your time to help. Really appreciated.